# In Ubuntu 18.04 no Sound in my laptop

Tags: sound, 18.04

In this image you can see no sounds are increased or decreased. How I can solve that problem?

[image: in this image you can see no sound are increase or decrease how I can solve that problem]

Comment: You are unable to change the volume because no output devices are detected as seen from this tab. The system has not detected your internal speakers, try connecting some external speakers and try again.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0403]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p&&index($0,n){p=1}p'`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: means laptop speaker is damage now?